# Obsolete comment flag handling

Tags: support, comments, flags

We've got well over 5000 obsolete comments on Arqade. Since these cannot be handled using any of the user level tools, [I have been flagging these so that they can be actioned by a moderator, however these appear to have been rejected en-mass?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6uTR.png)

All of these flags below are for comments that say things like "thanks", or "this worked for me", or "you should edit X into your answer/question" followed by a "I have edited X into my answer/question", all the sort of stuff that **doesn't need to exist**.

Only moderators can action stuff against comments, so this is very much in your remit to work on - this isn't something that a group of lowly users can band together to clean up - you **have** to do it because there's no other option available for them to be handled.

In addition to the flags I've raised here, I've also raised flags on multiple other Stack Exchange sites - including Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu, Super User, Server Fault, etc. These flags are *only* being rejected on Arqade, so I ask - what gives?

Comment: Well, if three users flag them, they should be auto-deleted, but that requires a bit of external coordination to work out in practice.

Comment: only for spam/offensive - not for obsolete

Comment: I could've sworn I've deleted other people's comments by simply flagging obsolete/chatty, and not just on SO.

Comment: @Troyen maybe someone else deleted it just as you finished flagging...

Comment: The irony of this does not escape me, but I just removed a bunch of comments that are now obsolete :/ - Thanks for keeping it civil folks.

Comment: I've flagged the occasional obsolete comment, but I find the lack of a 'reason' text box a bit annoying. For example, there was one comment about R18 games being banned in Australia. Without knowing that law had been overturned, how is a mod to determine the comments worth with a simple 'obsolete' flag? I've been using the custombox for this, but it seems wrong when there's a perfectly good flag reason just sitting there

Comment: @Robotnik the whole idea behind the obsolete / rude flag is a shortcut for common reasons. If your reason is custom, please use the custom box, that's the recommended approach.

Comment: You are correct, Troyen: that logic works for all comment flag types.

Comment: If you need to leave a detailed reason, flag the *post* @Robotnik.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> [the block decline of flags at the end yesterday] was indeed to **send the message of not to take this sort of "shotgun" approach to flagging**.

I'm sorry that this essentially boils down to some sort of miscommunication since not only did I have the above line, minus the bold, but very much there and explicitly saying what not to do, but I also figured that the many lines I had spoken about what is bad and not helpful, versus what is efficient and organized, would be directly implying the underlying intent without me needing to explicitly say "Don't do it". My bad, I should've been more direct and I understand that now, I messed up. I think underlying messages should be inherent and sticking only to what I said is a bit self-deprecating on the reader's part, though. But without further ado...

***Don't do it***.

Before I went to bed last night, I was working with others on the community team to compose a general announcement about these scripts. At that point I also got a complaint from the moderators that the walls of flags had returned, and so I piped up about that before wanting to sleep on this and come back at it with a rested head. In the mean time, **my team was the one that mass-declined your recent flag load**. It was only done on Arqade because the rest of the team was only aware that you were doing this on Arqade (and Arqade was the one, again, who poked us). You were in fact explicitly told why there was a decline in the previous incident, and so you persisted, and so we continued to decline for exactly that reason.

Here's pretty much what I got to writing last night with Shog9's help:

> Do not flag based purely on naive keyword searches. If I thought a simple keyword search was sufficient to remove these comments, I would remove them en masse and cut out the middlemen.
>
> If you come up with a system for identifying noisy/obsolete comments with a very, very low false-positive rate, post it up on meta & we'll just clear 'em all out. If you want to test your system by using the results to flag small batches, go for it - but don't just flood the queue, *especially if you're still in the early "naive keyword search" stages*.
>
> If you refuse to follow these guidelines and flood the flag queue with what amounts to noise, your ability to continue flagging at this rate - and possible a large chunk of your past flags - will be removed.
>
> This goes for everyone working on these scripts.

We're actually thinking of blocking this script from functioning any further on our API.

Arqade isn't the only site that has had issue with these flags. They are, however, the most recent ones that came to us about it. As well, different teams take different approaches - in this case the moderators had noted, which I relayed in our exchange, that they do like to check context on these things and don't always agree that all of these needed to be removed. A clarifying comment can be signal for some folks, and acknowledgment of the request for clarification is signal when joined with that kind of signal. That's how it worked over here. I can't speak to the experiences on other sites as I haven't analyzed the latest in flags or interrogated the mods there.

Yes, moderators are the only ones who can handle these. But this approach to flagging is far from an ideal means to get these taken care of. Rather than strongly urge you as before, I'm going to outright say it, if your main interest is clean up then the best way to get things done is the way that is most organized and most useful and helpful to those who actually have to do the job behind it. Your comfort level with regards to how much you're willing to do at once, your ability to do 200 edits in a single day, that's nice but it's not comparable to doing flags because that is no longer on what your comfort level is. And comfort dictates how well the job gets done.

I've not gotten to read the comment exchanges here and I shall be doing so shortly, but I wanted to get this message out first.

Comment: From your (moderators) perspective, it seems like flagging simply based on keywords, but there's a review process behind it. The user *reviews possible obsolete comments*, with the context of the post and decides whether or not to flag it or not. When done in reasonable amounts, it's helping the site, but in this case, the amounts were unreasonable.

Comment: @3ventic I've seen some of the flags, the comment threads it's been attached to and I can say that this is a rather generous approximation of what actually happened.

Comment: @badp It was less of an approximation and more of an ideal goal. Users need teaching and there needs to be more communication about flagging standards (which is happening now, and that's good).

Comment: @3ventic The review process being lost is a fault here, and part of that is because of the limitations of the flag queue system. If you pick out of a list of 500 comments that all have specific keywords, the moderators *still* get a list of 50+ comments that all have specific keywords, which doesn't give any illustration that the situation has changed.

Comment: Could this flag queue be added to the 20k privilege?  For us, that would add an additional 17 pairs of eyes.

Comment: @MBraedley Possibly. We're looking at a variety of options, but keep in mind that right now, only moderators actually have the ability to action on comments like that, because comment actions are... rather nuclear because of how low priority we consider them. There's a lot we'd need to work on to make this work in both a way that retains the work effort on handling them low, but avoids potential concerns about the access opening to something that no one can properly track.

Comment: @GraceNote That's why I suggested it be included in 20k and not 10k or 15k.  I'd be hesitant at best to allow 10kers to destroy comments.

Comment: @MBraedley We still lack proper tracking and handling. It's worse than a labyrinth to try and sift through this stuff, so until we have better tools all around, I'd rather not make a queue for this.

Answer (score 12):

Obsolete flags can only be handled by moderators. When you create work for the moderation team, you enter into a working relationship with them. You can decide to stop flagging at any time, they *can't* decide to stop handling your flags at any time. If your flags are detracting from the time that they feel they should be spending on issues that are more pressing than obsolete comments and request that you stop, *you need to stop*, especially if you're flagging in volume.

You're well aware that there is an election going on, which in and of itself is a large source of work for them. They've indicated that they're having issues keeping up with the load, a large portion of which you might *not* be aware that they're even doing. Moderators from *all over the network* are currently working with us to better refine the systems we have in place to combat serious abuse that has been affecting almost every site in our network.

There's also matters of sock puppetry, users circumventing system imposed restrictions, and lots of other things they deal with day to day that requires a significant amount of time and work. Just chasing down reports of suspicious voting can suck a half hour from your day. Duplicate answers on multiple posts can take an hour to clean up properly once all gets merged.

It's not that obsolete comments don't need to be cleaned up, they just don't need to flood the flag queue *right now* - they're not going anywhere, as you noted. Holding off on your flags is part of *working with a team of volunteers* - if they ask you to stop, please - just stop and wait for a more opportune time to carry out your cleanup.

I can't overstate just how much their current workload has been understated. Work with them, which sometimes means *holding off*.

Comment: I have no issues with holding off if the words "please hold off for a bit" are used - badp quoted some thing mentioned by Grace yesterday which was frankly quite cryptic with multiple possible meanings and is claiming this said "hold off for a bit" so as far as I'm concerned, I haven't been *asked* to wait *before* my cleanup effort was rejected without reason - as you say, it's a working relationship, before the response to this meta post the only actual communication in this relationship has been from my end, and even then it was poorly communicated after jumping to conclusions.

Comment: And yet, we have multiple accounts of "obsolete comment flags really just take a single click most of the time", moderators not actually saying "Tone it down a bit, this is too much.", and the argument not actually being supported by anything. I agree with the point that, if the moderators feel it's too much one should tone it down, but I disagree that the moderators have convincingly made that point at any time.

Comment: @FEichinger I think 90% of the problem here is frustration. This could be a _good_ thing, but just at a slightly later time in the future. The thing to do is just hold off, let them get some more help in and indoctrinated, let the stress levels cool down a bit, and then look at it again. Remember, they are volunteers, if they say 'hey, too much, this isn't really urgent ..' the community really needs to respect that in order to keep the relationship working.

Comment: @TimPost Then they should *say so*. That's really the whole point being made here. The only indicator kalina got was Grace saying it "is not all that helpful to actually getting things actioned on", not "give them a break/wait until the elections are over/let them have some more time". And, the other important point here, **why were the flags unceremoniously declined?** They were valid, some were even actioned - they were declined anyway, and nothing here ever addressed *why that happened*, instead accusing kalina of "knowing she shouldn't have cast them in the first place" - which is nonsense

Comment: @FEichinger From what I can gather (I'm honestly just walking into this), they didn't have a chance to before it continued. I think a big catalyst here was just mis/missed communication. Give me a bit to get through a bunch of transcripts.

Comment: @TimPost Flags are rate-limited like anything else, so the "it continued before they could say something!" part isn't all that relevant - once the limit is reached, the flags can't continue, and from that point there's *lots* of time to tell the user to stop. When there are too many flags, then, they can be worked off over the next days, while the user stopped flagging like that. I'm not seeing the problem that warrants mass-declining.

Comment: @FEichinger The push happened close to UTC midnight.

Comment: @badp At any point could any of you have given a clear "Stop!". All I'm saying is that whenever she takes a break from casting those flags, she would be perfectly capable of reading a warning she gets via ping or mod message. And those breaks are *bound* to happen, because of the system's own constraints.

Comment: @TimPost [yes, they were discussing it internally when the complaining started](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13567955#13567955)

Answer (score 10):

> All of these flags below are for comments that say things like "thanks", or "this worked for me", or "you should edit X into your answer/question" followed by a "I have edited X into my answer/question", all the sort of stuff that **doesn't need to exist**.

**I agree**, all of these comments should be nuked, preferably from orbit. I find it unfortunate that there's no way for non-mod but high-rep users to already handle them, but that is the way it is.

**However**, if you - or anyone - have any plan on doing a large-scale cleaning operation, standard flagging is not the best approach - it's better to coordinate it in meta beforehand. For example:

- [How should I write tag wikis?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/cleanup-2013-its-time-for-meaningful-and-consistent-tag-wikis)
- [The Great Arqade Clean-Up of 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)

Why is it important to coordinate it in advance? Because unlike just organically browsing the site and modifying things, these sort of sweeping cleanups have repercussions:

- Tons of wiki edits will flood the review queue, hiding other issues
- Tons of tag edits will flood the front page, hiding other new/edited questions
- Tons of flags will flood the flag queues, hiding other flags

By coordinating these things in advance, you can distribute the effort between different users (including mods) and distribute it over time.

**In short, and more to the point** - if you browse the site and see such a comment, I think you should flag it as obsolete. But if you plan on searching the site for these comments and flagging many at a time, please coordinate it in advance on meta.

Comment: I agree, but what would be the best way to coordinate a comment cleanup when most people don't have access to mass-flagging tools, and comments are spread out a lot, and we can only flag so many comments a day?

Comment: Excellent answer. I would even ask, why wasn't this explanation given to her ahead of time, instead of just shunting her off to the oblivion of rejected flags? Not to mention the personal attacks about her "abuse of flagging".

Comment: @AviD regarding why the flag were rejected in this instance - I refer you to [Grace's future answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8368).

Comment: okay, great. But the lack of communication here is still at issue, in my opinion - as I've mentioned to other mods, it does apparently seem like an issue of prejudice. Now, I'm not saying whether it is justified or not, but just that it is relevant.

Comment: @3ventic answering questions as to "how it can be done" is another great utility for the "coordination in advance" meta post.

Comment: @AviD indeed it is. I won't deny that communication between mods and users - and particularly, between mods and mods - is sometimes lacking; perhaps that should be a meta topic by itself. But it's not that simple in this particular case, and again, Grace's post has some more information about that.

Comment: So I've been going through the D3 questions lately with the new patch and there are a lot of comments that are now obsolete and hiding newer comments asking for updates or clarifications to mechanics changes.  Should I flag each comment individually as obsolete, flag the post and say "nuke all comments in this topic", or just ignore them?

Comment: @Troyen Flagging the post is preferable if you believe all/many of the comments need to be removed.

Answer (score 9):

What gives is that you're flooding a moderation team that's been [struggling with keeping up with ~2,300 flags/quarter](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=13553348#13553348), as I disclosed yesterday before all of this started.

You are fully aware that:

- We are struggling with keeping up with load, which is the whole point of the current elections for *three* slots
- Comments are *not* a priority, and you're distracting us from the rest of the website
- With three extra moderators that are as active as we are, we'd be able to handle about 3,500 flags/quarter, and [you're planning to flag 2,200/quarter](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=13568069#13568069) at 25/day (which is a generous reading of 25 a "time") as some sort of concession.
- We struggled with dealing with your first wave of 85 flags; the five of us took a portion of the flood each and failed to handle them consistently, [and you complained about it loudly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=13566718#13566718)
- [You were asked to stop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=13568039#13568039) before you raised the new wave of flags. So [you decided you'd flag even more](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=13568009#13568009).
- Flag numbers are shown prominently in the election and some of our candidates are being rewarded handsomely for their flagging history.

You continued anyway, and your new wave of flags was denied at no penalty whatsoever to your account except for a completely private number of declined flags.

So the obvious rational thing to do is ask on meta, complaining that doing the thing you were warned about doing is not working out nearly as well as you'd have hoped.

We have limited resources. We have to make the best of them. Waves and waves of menial comment flags that solve no actual problem on the site are, on the contrary, a problem.

We care about the site, we have a responsibility to care about the site. But our responsibility is a long term one; there is literally no end to our mandate. We set your flags on fire *because* we care.

What we *don't* care about is burning ourselves out to the altar of your flag number so you have a better shot during the next elections.

You were warned by Grace. You were warned by all of your flags being rejected. This is your third warning.

This line ends the amount of time I have to properly give this subject my attention at this point in time.

Comment: "Asked to stop" is a little convenient with the truth - based on the comment you linked. In fact, my methodology was criticised and I took this on board and ensured that my next flags flagged every single comment that needed removing - which is what the conversation around the chat post you linked was actually about.

Comment: "I'll reiterate that doing 100 flags [...] is not all that helpful" is a very polite way of saying "please stop." It still does means, "please stop."

Comment: I'm extremely disappointed you think this has anything to do with a flag number, this is purely about cleaning up the site - an activity I have discussed at length targeting each separate part of the site (tags, tag wikis, questions, etc). You only have to look at my meta history to realise that cleaning up is one of my primary activities, why you would jump to the conclusion otherwise is beyond me.

Comment: "So the obvious rational thing to do is ask on meta" - yes it was, and to view it as a complaint when I was in fact merely asking what is going on - **since I hadn't heard anything from the Arqade moderator team regarding any of this, even after I had asked in chat lastnight** (which resulted in a "haven't got time to talk about it" response), meta is the correct place to ask this question to get a specific answer.

Comment: I specifically stated to Grace I was going to do more, no comment along the lines of "no, don't" was made, therefore I can't agree with your conclusion. If you don't want me to do something - **state it very specifically so that these misunderstandings do not occur**. I've always made this very clear, cryptic nonsense with multiple interpretations is not a warning - clear, concise statements are warnings.

Comment: "Too much load" is an incredibly stupid reason for rejecting perfectly valid flags. Accept and reject flags based on each individual flags merits, not for some silly reason like this...

Comment: Arqade [currently has 6 moderators](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) and plans to get 9. On average, that makes about 133 flags per moderator per month, or a grand total of *4* flags per day. I'm sorry, but **4 flags per day**? I know there's more to the job than flag handling, but that is just ridiculously low.

Comment: @badp I'm curious, is the problem with these flags the *source* of the flagging, or the *type* of flag? Because from here, it really does look like the former. Obsolete comment flags are the easiest to validate, 90% of the time they are clear and unambiguous enough to merit a quick `delete comment` without further investigation. So I'm just curious, if this is a policy of de-prioritizing comment flags, or a way of handling a perceived trollflagger?

Comment: The SO mods are always saying that comment flags are the easiest to handle, they can just nuke them in seconds without even loading the post.  Are comment flags really that much of a burden on Arqade?

Comment: @AviD Just a simple `floor()`. It doesn't really matter what the value ends up being, it's in the single-digits ballpark and that is concerning.

Comment: @FEichinger oh I completely agree, thats not a lot for a medium size site, and Arkade is no longer medium sized. On the other hand, your comment that I flagged was deleted.... ;-)

Comment: @AviD I self-deleted that one after reading yours. ;)

Comment: @FEichinger That's not 4 flags per day, but 4 flagged posts per day. January is kind of a lull; the average last quarter was 2,366+ flagged posts or ---20--- 26/day. 25 posts a day per 90 days is 2,250.

Comment: Then why are you bringing up those numbers in the first place? You made it look like that was the upper cap you could possibly handle, when in fact it's just *what's there*. And if it's just *what's there*, what prevents you from handling more flags, now that there *are more flags there*?

Comment: @FEichinger because those were the numbers I brought out yesterday. I'm kind of busy and can't do ALL of the stats.

Comment: But they're completely irrelevant for the discussion at hand. Why are kalina's flags getting rejected? Clearly it's neither that they're invalid, nor that you don't have the manpower to handle them - what is the problem with the flags, in plain terms?

Comment: @FEichinger I just said that we're handling ---20--- 26 and kalina wants to dump 25 more on it.

Comment: And you also just said that the only reason you're currently only handling 20 is *because that's all the flags there are*, not that that's the max you could handle.

Comment: @FEichinger Why do you think we decided, a few weeks ago, right after the Christmas spike, to hold elections in the first place?!

Comment: I'm fully aware that there *is* a cap on your activity. I am merely saying that you have yet to come forward on what that *is*. The numbers you presented were 1.) far too low to be taken seriously for this argument and 2.) - as you said yourself - not the actual cap, but the matter-of-fact *existing flags* - and those are all getting handled pretty quickly.

Comment: I have no problem with you saying you can't handle the load. But presenting numbers in the *single-digit figures* as oh-so-terribly-heavy a load is unsettling.

Comment: @FEichinger Regardless of what your personal opinion of the amount of time mods are supposed to spend on the site, an increase of 100% of flags by one user over what ultimately is a non-issue ("Thanks for the edit!"/"See my edited post" comments) is not welcome. I think it's a reasonable point to make.

Comment: (If we take that 2,366 flags on average per month you cited above, leads me to 2366*3/90/6 = 13.1 -- We can upscale it to account for off days, but in comparison to the previous calculation, there's still something odd about that.) All I was saying was that the argument that this would, **factually** be too heavy a load *is not supported by what you're presenting*.

Comment: I don't disagree that doubling the total flags could pose a problem. I don't even disagree that obsolete comments are ultimately a non-issue. But the way this has been handled and the arguments you've been bringing forth here are *not in line with that*, and make me think this is about something completely other than "these flags are not worth the effort".

Comment: @badp A lot of this seems to be miscommunication. I'm right there with Kalina in not seeing Grace's message as "please stop" or "please wait until after elections". In the interest of preventing further miscommunications, what exactly is meant by the "warnings" that you mention this meta post is the third of? Is it a threat that further action result in suspension or some such? I make no argument for or against that, I'm just not clear on what exactly you were implying there. I also feel like the first two "warnings" were not clear as "warnings". Let's be clear to avoid miscommunication.

Comment: On a different note, next time we have elections it would be awesome to hear from the moderator team about some specific reasons they felt new moderators were warranted. Knowing that they feel overwhelmed by the flag queue might help when casting votes.

Comment: @Sterno Are you asking me to rule out suspension as a possible consequence? You know it's not something I can do. As for "we're swamped down, please slow": when you're doing proper flagging work, every flag you're making is a post we wouldn't have to stumble upon on your own. It's much more important to have it linger in our flag queue a little longer than it is to lose it.

Comment: Suspension as a possible consequence of valid flagging? Overzealousness, while annoying, is not a crime.

Comment: @AviD Yes: suspension from the abuse of the flag button is a definite possibility. Any sort of abuse may result in suspension.

Comment: Abuse -> suspension, surely. But how is this abuse of the flag button? Those flags were valid! Or is what you are saying is that they are NOT valid...?

Comment: @badp I'm specifically not asking you to rule something out. I'm asking you what you were implying with your warnings, and I'm also trying to indicate that the first two things you considered to be warnings did not appear to me (or, it seems, Kalina) to be warnings. If someone keeps flagging stuff after you clearly tell them not to, then by all means take the action you feel appropriate. If the first two things were truly warnings that would result in some sort of action such as suspension, I feel they should have been much clearer. I would never suspect that a flag being decline is a warning.

Comment: And, if the mod team does decide - for whatever reason - to set a policy of no comment flags, that should be uniformly implemented and enforced, and announced via meta post and in the faq, not in a single chat message to a single specific user.

Comment: @AviD all we ask is for common sense -- as badp stated before, we (he) came clean we were overwhelmed by flags, and the response was to flag all the things...

Comment: @Sterno Banning by sum of smaller things is something we have done. One declined flag barely registers. About 50 in a day, on the other hand...

Comment: @badp Which brings us back to *why they were declined in the first place*.

Comment: @badp Except clearly, 50 at once *didn't* register. I think that's the entire issue here. You have an expectation that those denials carried a certain message, and Kalina was confused about what message they were trying to convey. I probably would have been as well. Hence, this meta post asking for clarification. My entire point is that I think in cases like these, a clear message would be very useful, rather than expecting the user to glean the hidden meaning behind the flag denials.

Comment: @FEichinger ... which is the point of this meta post anyway, isn't it.

Comment: @Sterno I did take the time to explain what was wrong in my answer, yes?

Comment: @badp Indeed! Meta is working as intended. However, you seem annoyed that such explanation was necessary. Perhaps I am misjudging your demeanor.

Comment: @Sterno I thought Grace provided an adequate explanation.

Comment: @badp no, you didn't. Besides commenting on the modload, the rest basically read as "thanks luv, but dont bother flagging here. We have *good* users for that."

Comment: @AviD Please *don't* bother flagging all comments that thank somebody for editing. Please *don't* bother flagging all comments that notify that something have been edited. Please *don't* go on similar flagging sprees, at least for comments, at least for minor situations like this. IOW: please *do* apply common sense.

Comment: @badp I didn't fully understand what Grace was trying to say. Was it stop? Was it "slow down?" Was it "do less per day?" Was it "approach it differently and make sure you don't miss other contextual comments around the one being deleted?" I don't think Kalina knew either. This seems to have become quite escalated because what I see as a simple misunderstanding is being interpreted as willful ignorance and disregard. I think it would benefit both sides to give the other the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @badp common sense would agree only with your last point. All those *should* be flagged, as one runs across them. Flagging "sprees" on these, on the other hand, are pointless and overkill.

Comment: To be clear, if an experienced and high-rep user has the time, energy and inclination to go on a flagging spree - this *should be encouraged*. It seems that some direction could have been given here, away from low-priority comments, and towards higher-priority issues that should be spreed upon.

Comment: @AviD I *want* to encourage good use of the site. I *want* to encourage engaged users to be engaged. I *don't* want to encourage abuse. What happened yesterday was abuse, regardless of intentions.

Comment: @badp no, it was not abuse, and it was not even close. What it was, was an instance of good-intentioned-but-misdirected application of a combination of OCD and ADHD. Put aside her history, and your personal (possibly justified) feelings towards a specific user, and treat it for what it *is*, not how it makes you feel.

Comment: @AviD If _you_, a person I barely know, given the opportunity, flagged *more than one hundred comments in a single day, and the comments were not obviously wrong, just unnecessary*, I would consider it abuse. Because it is. Abuse is what it is. It being abuse.

Comment: @badp So you do admit personal feelings did affect you when dealing with this matter?

Comment: @badp So where is the meta post documenting that mass valid flagging is abuse?

Comment: @TerryChia That's the opposite of what I've just said: I would've been disappointed even if Grace Note did that. Also, there is no wall of text that enumerates exhaustively all kind of things you can do that can be considered abuse. There should be none. It would be a waste of time. It would be a forum troll's heaven. No.

Comment: @badp THEY ARE VALID FLAGS FOR GOD'S SAKE. If the community doesn't like mass flagging, DOCUMENT IT ON META. That's what meta is for! The way it appears to me (an outsider to this community) is a mod dictating to a user what he can and can not do at his own discretion because it inconveniences him. That isn't the type of community I want to be a part of.

Comment: @TerryChia Have you read the other answers? What makes you think _I_ was the person who dismissed the flags? Spoiler alert: *I wasn't.*

Comment: @badp I disagree. There are flag limits for this exact reason, and if 100 valid flags is too many at once, *the system should lower the limits*. If a user is granted e.g. 100 flags to flag, it is not just permitted, it is encouragement to *use* them, to flag validly removable comments.

Comment: @AviD If you are not going to exercise common sense while pressing the buttons the website offers you the ability to press, you're gonna have a bad time. The flag limit was geared for Stack Overflow. We get 42 questions a day. *The whole point of having moderators is to enforce common sense and policies when the website fails to do so.*

Comment: @badp I dont disagree about that, and I do totally understand the issue of load. Just pointing out that a little more even-handedness, and transparency, are probably called for here. And a lot less emotion.

Comment: @AviD Flagging is a private business by default - especially for flags where only mods can see and act on.

Comment: @TerryChia I don't think there is a specific post on this here on Arqade, but the general theme that individually okay actions can be problematic en masse is discussed rather extensively across the network. The most common instance of this is mass-editing, but I remember some previous cases of mass flagging on other sites that were problematic. Meta doesn't need to address every single issue in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In other network sites these comments are deleted by moderators frequently without flagging.  It would be interesting to hear the moderator concerned comment, since the lack of consequences for the commenting user (in the event of a comment being flagged obsolete) leaves no apparent reason for the flags' rejection if the circumstances Kalina cites are correct.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going with this. There already is a specific "obsolete" flag for this reason, and aside from *the comment being deleted* there *are* no consequences.

Comment: Aah, so there is.

Comment: @FalconMomot Obsolete flags cannot be handled by sum of flags.

Comment: Oh!  Good to know.

Comment: @badp [Grace Note has just posted saying otherwise](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8367/should-minor-comments-be-flagged#comment24737_8372)

Comment: @BillyMailman TIL. That's pretty bad, but oh well.