# What can I do to be able to raise comment flags more often?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

Backstory:

I have recently have been flagging comments (especially on my old posts) a lot; I flagged cca. 40 (30?) comments as obsolete, too chatty or not constructive in a spread of around a week. All but one got marked as helpful, until two days ago, from when all my comment flags I raised were declined, including one I raised to explain *why* they got declined.

This brought me to Meta, where I found that [this behavior was already observed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8361/obsolete-comment-flag-handling), and that a mod gave valid explanation on why having a "shotgun" approach to flagging isn't encouraged (at all), or even really super-helpful.

Currently my flagging statistics count 255 net helpful flags. That gives me a limit of ***37***  per day. From that, under 10 a day were used for old comments, leaving many flags "unused", and maybe even *unusable*.

---

I'd like to have the option of mass-flagging of unneeded comments, but sadly, every such flag needs to be reviewed be a mod - so doing this is actually just giving them extra work, on behalf of doing more important things.

**Is there any way, or anything I could do, to keep this practice sustainable?**

Answer (score 5):

Nope. There's no way to flag comments en-masse.

And, really, ask yourself if you're providing value; these comments have been around for years, not doing any harm, and they require a mod to take a look at and delete. Flagging a lot of them just means you're creating a lot of work for mods, with very little value.

Flagging comments on a new question or one under dispute? Sure, that might need some attention. if a question hasn't been touched in years, though, is it really worth it to clean up a comment or two? From a strict quality point of view, yes, it is, as its supposed to be an encyclopedic Q&A. Add in the level of oversight required, though, and the value goes way way down.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. To TL;DR it a bit: Ideally, one should flag only unneeded/harmful  comments on recently active posts, and posts with lots of attention (either of registered users or lots of visitors.

Answer (score 3):

If a user has many comments that are problematic, please raise a custom flag against any one of them and explain a bit in the custom flag reason. Handling this sort of thing is a mod's job, and it only takes one flag to bring it to our attention.

Comment: This was about the answer I was ready for. I guess the approach you described here goes the same for posts with lot's of unneeded/harmful comments - one should flag the post, not all the comments. Thanks for helping me out.