# Could we have the preferred tag wiki format indicated to suggesting users?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

**Related:** [How should I write tag wikis?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/)

Currently, there is no easy way to find the community's preferred tag wiki format apart from specifically searching meta for it. The sidebar has a link to the generic [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) about helpful tag wikis:

[image: What are tag wikis? See our advice on writing great tag wikis.]

but there's no link whatsoever to the meta post about it. The decline reason has the same problem of linking only to the generic blog post without any mention of the meta:

> **wiki not helpful**
>
> This edit does not follow any of our [tag wiki guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) and is unlikely to help instruct future visitors in the appropriate use of the tag.

Could a link or at least a mention of the meta post be added somewhere when editing, and to the decline reason?

Comment: This. All the this. I've had to use a custom reject reason for almost every tag wiki edit I've rejected, because of the format thing.

Comment: i had no idea what i did wrong when suggesting a tag wiki until that link was shown me in chat. If that is the pattern of all wikis, why not have it prepared when suggesting a new tag? So people only need to fill the brackets.

Comment: @Wandang it's used for tags that fit the format (games, mods, programs), but there are tags like [tag:achievements] and [tag:technical-issues], which don't have release date, developer, genre or anything of the sort.

Comment: It needs to be added to the FAQ tag, that's for sure.

Comment: I basically like @BillyMailman's tag wiki apart from the position of the [Release Year], like when the game is release matters very, very little.

Comment: @Gwen sometimes it does - there are numerous instances where a game is re-released with the same name and by having release date in the tag wiki it makes it clearer which game is being talked about (I know we have some tags that are game-year, but we also have some that aren't like this, and it's important to be clear)

Comment: @kalina yes, sometimes it matters, but not often enough to justify it being the _second word of the excerpt_, which is what I'm saying.

Comment: @gwen this is the wrong place to have this particular discussion. We should [move this to the tag wiki question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7845/52800) so that all related discussion regarding the accepted format is kept together.