# Tag Request for Game-of-War

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Can game-of-war be a tag on the main site, please?

> **Game of War:** Fire Age is a revolutionary free-to-play MMO developed by Machine Zone (creators of Global War, iMob, and Original Gangstaz). The game is a truly social experience that leverages your ability to manage resources while working with an alliance of other live players to carve out a territory and control the world!
>
> Armed with only your city, hero, and desire for conquest, you are thrown into a massive world where players challenge each other for overall global supremacy. Game of War: Fire Age blends genres and delivers a board-game style feel with RTS (real-time strategy) and MMO elements.

[Reference of Game of War](http://gow-fireage.wikia.com/wiki/Game_of_War_Wiki).

Comment: Just so you know (and don't get disheartened) as well, downvotes on meta simply mean disagreement, and there's no rep loss associated with them (or rep gain from upvotes for that matter). So people are just expressing disagreement that we should preemptively create tags :)

Comment: Thanks @Robotnik :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We generally don't proactively add game tags. In fact, tags without any questions associated with them are automatically removed after a while.

**When** a question is asked about a game for which there is no tag yet, **then** the question asker should either create the tag along with the question - if that user has [the create-tag privilege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) - or it should be flagged for moderator attention with request for adding a tag.

Once a tag exists, any user can propose an edit to the excerpt of that tag or to the tag's wiki (and [very-high rep users can edit it directly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)).

By the way, once you do want to edit some description to a tag, just copying some promotional information about the game is not very helpful. Here's a useful link on how to properly write the excerpts and wiki pages for tags: 
 [How should I write tag wikis?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/how-should-i-write-tag-wikis)