# A suitable tag for Bos Wars?

Tags: support, tags

I wanted to post a question about [Bos Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bos_Wars), but no tag exists for the game. My reputation is not high enough to create a new tag. I am unable to post the question because I cannot find any other existing tag that is suitable for the question.

I found a somewhat related thread on meta: [Tag Request for Game-of-War](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8448/tag-request-for-game-of-war)

> When a question is asked about a game for which there is no tag yet,
>   then the question asker should either create the tag along with the
>   question - if that user has the create-tag privilege - or it should be
>   flagged for moderator attention with request for adding a tag.

But I am unable to post questions that don't have tags in the first place. How can I post my question?

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/20306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the question, add any tag that exists, and then comment asking for the new tag to be created, or flag the question for moderator attention asking them to change the tag. We can't create a tag without having a question to attach it to.

Comment: Thank you. Posted the question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/350979/bos-wars-how-to-stop-cannons-from-attacking-enemy-units