# How long will my edit ban last?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I was editing some of the wiki tags, and made a rather basic mistake of copying material from sites like Wikipedia. This may seem like blatant error to many of you, but I am a relatively new user, and didn't know that was against the rules.

Because five of my suggested edits were rejected, I have been (hoepfully) temporarily banned from editing questions and answers. Does anyone know how long this ban will last? Is it permanent? I really didn't mean to break the rules, I was just unaware of them at the time, and have legitimate edit suggestions for other posts.

Answer (score 7):

Your edit ban is temporary, and you'll be resume making suggested edits again next week. In the meantime, though, you might want to take some time to ask yourself *why* your edits were rejects, or you might find yourself suspended from edits again.

I can see by looking at your history, though, that you might want to take a look at [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/how-should-i-write-tag-wikis), and also keep in mind that you shouldn't copy/paste text from other sources, even Wikipedia, to be included in a tag wiki.

Comment: I know exactly why I was banned, because I copied from Wikipedia, not understanding that I couldn't at the time

Comment: @ThePickleTickler If you're gonna copy from Wikipedia, make sure to indicate your source by linking to the source article. Both Wikipedia and Stack Exchange use the CC-BY-SA license. Basically you can copy text from one to the other as long as you indicate your source and link to the source page.

Comment: That said, we generally dislike straight up copy pastes from Wikipedia, even with attribution; we want something that is helpful for this community specifically.