# Are my tag edit privileges revoked?

Tags: support, editing, tag-wiki

When I go to attempt to edit a tag wiki, it redirects me to this page:

[image: Tag Redirect]

The tag definitely isn't deleted and it's also not a post as this words it.  What is going on?

Comment: [Works for me](https://0ws.pw/kd70.png), so either it is a bug, or your tag edit privileges are revoked.

Comment: Which tag wiki are you trying to edit?

Comment: Any of them do this.  The one in the screenshot is Skyrim (I didn't want to edit Skyrim, I just chose that one for the picture).

Comment: @TimmyJim can you try with another browser?

Comment: Still happens in Edge and IE.

Comment: Try Firefox, the slow but never-bugging, unstoppable browser :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit ban is temporary, and will be lifted automatically in about a week or so. In the meantime, you can review your suggested edits and any rejection reasons on your ['All Actions' tab](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on your profile. This should at least give you a reason as to why your edits were being rejected.

Note that the community is a little more stringent when it comes to tag wiki edits (when compared to Suggested Edits on questions and answers), so make sure any edits are substantial and actually improve the wiki/excerpt. A few years ago as part of a larger cleanup effort, the community decided on a format for Tag excerpts and Wikis that works well for us so have a look at this question and the answer for some guidance: [How should I write tag wikis?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7837/28182)

Comment: Note if you're looking for some tag wikis to edit, there is also a post we (occasionally) maintain listing tags without any wiki at all: [Top tags requiring a tag wiki](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1594/28182) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your account is blocked from suggested edits - this includes editing of tag wiki pages, and is the reason you are getting this page.

Comment: Why am I blocked?

Comment: Probably too many rejected suggested edits in a row.

Comment: Is there a way to repeal this? I was editing a lot of tags I'll admit, but nothing that I would expect to get rejected.

Comment: You can flag one of your posts for moderator attention - ask your site moderators for that (I am a developer at Stack Exchange - only got into this post because it was tagged with bug).

Comment: I suppose I will flag this post then. I appreciate your answer and time.