# Make Tag Wiki edit limits/bans more obvious (Why is it not explained nicely?)

Tags: feature-request, editing, tag-wiki

In the past few minutes I submitted 3 tag-wiki edits. Lacking sufficient reputation, they are placed in a queue for peer review. When I now try to edit the fourth tag it seems I cannot do that. There is no explanation why.

For example, going to the [car-mechanic-simulator-2018](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-mechanic-simulator-2018) page, and clicking the "help us create it" link. The link points to the edit-tag-wiki page (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/12087), but instead I end up being redirected to the info page (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/car-mechanic-simulator-2018/info)
Where I cannot edit the tag.

If there is a hard limit of how many tags can be edited, or some other ban in place, please at least explain to the user that they have reached that limit and other relevant details.

Comment: The best thing I've found is on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/201625), which states "at-most 5 pending suggested edits" before being blocked. However that was from 2016, and not sure if that has changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are my tag edit privileges revoked?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12035/are-my-tag-edit-privileges-revoked)

Comment: Is this still an issue for you MeanGreen? If not, we can probably close this post as a duplicate of the one I linked.

Comment: @TimmyJim  I think the idea of "make the edit ban more obvious" can stand on it's own as a [feature-request], right? I've edited the title a bit to reflect this.

Comment: @TimmyJim as far as I can tell there was no temporary ban applied and my last rejected wiki tag edit was 2 months ago. I still believe I reached a max pending suggested edit limit. But maybe as a mod you can see more details on my account.

Comment: Unfortunately not - there doesn't appear to be anything on your profile indicating any kind of ban or restriction.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen a long time ago way back when I was still new to the site: [Are my tag edit privileges revoked?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12035/are-my-tag-edit-privileges-revoked).  The answer by Oded (who was at the time a Stack Overflow employee) claims it was because I was blocked from making tag edits.

You are likely temporarily banned from performing tag wiki edits. It will resolve itself eventually. The likely reason is you may have had too many rejected edits, and you are now on a cool down. Or, it could be because of too many edits currently pending.  I can't say for sure though.

Comment: I've reviewed and had to reject one of OP's tag wiki edits. @MeanGreen please see the meta post, [How should I write tag wikis?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7837/4797) on how to write tag wikis on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @galacticninja