# Edit tag wiki has a hidden pending edits queue limit?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

In the past couple of minutes I proposed a couple of tag wiki edits. After the third or so edit, the edit page no longer shows the usage guidance and tag wiki as editable fields. Instead the placeholder text is shown as a simple paragraph.

Is there a hidden limit to the number of proposed edits that I can have queued before allowing more edits?
If so, would a proper message not be much clearer to anyone in this situation? If not, what is happening here? I specifically tried to edit the [aliens-dark-descent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens-dark-descent) tag via https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/aliens-dark-descent/info, reached after clicking 'can you help us create it' on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens-dark-descent.

Comment: one thing to note when creating tag wikis, we try to keep a fairly standard format. See [pokemon-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/pokemon-go/info) for a good example on how it should look and the sort of info we are looking to add to the wiki.

Comment: Can't the default placeholder text be changed to a template of the pokemon-go example?

Comment: not sure if that is something that can be changed or not. i can ask a cm about it

Comment: @MeanGreen I appreciate your efforts to make our tag wikis more informative and helpful. However, I noticed that some of your suggested edits seem to be [copied from Wikipedia](/help/referencing) and/or do not follow one of the formats suggested by our [tag wiki guidelines](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7837/4797). To [avoid plagiarism](/help/referencing), I recommend that you write the tag wiki in your own words, following one of the formats provided by our guidelines.

Comment: @galacticninja thanks for the feedback. I'll follow those guidelines next time I propose an edit. As you can see from the original question and the fact the guidelines are not mentioned on the edit page itself, and the 'See our advice on writing great tag wikis.' barely noticable, I think there is room to make these recommendations easier to find for inexperienced editors. I've proposed multiple edits like this in the past and almost all were accepted without any comments. This suggests the recommendations are not clear to reviewers either.

Comment: @MeanGreen I agree that our tag wiki guidelines could be made clearer and easier to find. On: "*I’ve proposed multiple edits like this in the past and almost all were accepted without any comments*" – this is because having a tag wiki, even though it does not follow one of the formats suggested by our guidelines, is preferable to having no tag wiki. So some of the reviewers are likely to accept tag wiki suggestions even though they do not follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand you are limited to 5 pending suggested edits. So whether you are suggesting edits to posts, tag wikis, or a combination, you can only have 5 pending suggested edits.

See [Shog's post for more details.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits/281202#281202)

Comment: I actually saw that post but misunderstood it!  To add, if too many of your edits get rejected, you also will get suspended from editing temporarily

Comment: @TimmyJim Was the OP suspended from making tag wiki edits (again)? I'm asking because the OP posted something similar back in 2021 and you answered back then that they are likely temporarily banned from performing tag wiki edits: [Make Tag Wiki edit limits/bans more obvious (Why is it not explained nicely?)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16170/4797) This seems like the same issue.

Comment: @galacticninja I checked what is available to us moderators and nothing indicated that they were banned from editing. Its likely what this answer describes - they were just limited until their edits got through the queue.  As for their 2021 post I dont recall the details. For my personal example though it was [believed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12035/are-my-tag-edit-privileges-revoked#comment37769_12040) to be because I was banned due to rejected edits. Shame on me!