# Tag wiki reviews - editing text

Tags: support, tag-wiki

When I'm reviewing a tag wiki addition, it prompts me to

> Approve, reject, or **improve** edits suggested by users

Most of the reviews I've done are in cases where there is no existing entry and someone decided to add it - great, I will accept if its fine. For short excerpts, there tends to be less problems with formatting.

However, recently I came across a review where the game does need an excerpt, but the suggested edit is just a run-on sentence. I'd prefer to edit and accept it (rather than having nothing at all) but that doesn't seem possible.

Approve or reject in such cases is straightforward, but how should I improve it? The prompt appears to be only applicable for users above 20k rep, which is quite far away.

Comment: Before you worry about improving edits, you might want to make sure that you're actually *reviewing* [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/233699) [edits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/233695) (here's [a third one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/233673)). I've noticed almost all of the approved plagiarized edits recently have had your approval on them. See [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12581/162442).

Comment: @Vemonus Thanks for the heads-up - I hadn't seen that post nor did I realize plagiarism was an issue to look out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Yuuki mentioned, only 20k+ users can improve tag wiki edits, as improvements do not require approval and only 20k+ users can make tag wiki edits without approval. Therefore, if you think a proposed edit to a wiki is good except for a small typo or grammatical error, just approve the edit and check back later to see if the edit has been approved. If it has, then propose your own edit to the tag wiki to correct the typo(s) and/or grammatical error(s). That way it is a win-win and both users get +2 rep for improving the tag wiki, instead of rejecting and punishing the user for making a small error in an otherwise good improvement.

Comment: Except, not all users will get that +2 rep.  Only if they are under 2k reputation.

Comment: @TimmyJim 20k*. These are tag wikis

Comment: I thought I stopped earning rep on all edits after 2k, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @TimmyJim you get 2 rep for any edit you make that has to be approved. Provided that the edit does get approved.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, about the best you can do is either approve or reject the edit and continue to edit in your own version. The improve privilege to restricted to 20k+ users for good reason: improvements are made without requiring approval and therefore only trusted users are allowed to improve edits. If you have reason to believe that this privilege should have a lower threshold, feel free to bring it up on the [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, I certainly don't want to lower thresholds - just wondered why 'improve' is mentioned when I can't actually do anything about it.

Comment: Probably because improving is something that can be, just not done by everyone. And no one feels that it's necessary to provide rep-specific text.