# How to avoid Tag Wiki/Excerpt plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, plagiarism

I am sorry to bring up an old dead topic yet again.

I am running into rejection on tag wiki excerpts because of plagiarism yet again.

I have been following [advice posted on meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7845/15184) about writing tag wikis.

According to that accepted answer

> A [Release Year] [Genre], developed by [Developer] for [Platforms]. [Short Description].

I have been posting excerpts in a similar vein for example

> A 2018 hack and slash action-adventure video game developed by Gunfire Games and published by THQ Nordic. It is a sequel to Darksiders II and the final entry in the Darksiders series.

I generally also include if a game is a sequel.

But they stand to be rejected for plagiarism from Wikipedia. A [meta discussion on the subject](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/could-tag-wiki-reviewers-please-check-for-plagiarism) suggests Googling the tag wiki text/excerpt for plagiarism.

I honestly do not know how I can write one or two sentences about the year, genre, developer, sequel of without it matching some wiki/Steam store site.

So I would like to revisit what format should tag wiki excerpts look like? I also welcome advice on how I can structure my sentence to avoid plagiarism from wikis on the subject.

Comment: Excerpts are tricky for this, since the format is pretty standard anywhere online. However, I recently submitted two rejects for copying of other parts. Speaking personally, if it's *just* this part that happens to be exactly Wikipedia, I completely don't care. The spirit of the "copied content" rejection reason doesn't really apply to basic information formatting, in my opinion. Don't copy from Wikipedia, but if it happens to line up, and that's all that lines up, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -3):

It's not technically plagiarism because the information on Wikipedia is creative commons.

You can plagiarize something in the public domain.

So, it should not even matter.

Comment: While this may be almost how copyright infringement works (it isn't, since it's an attribution license), it isn't how plagiarism works. "Copied Content" is an explicit rejection reason for tag wiki edits.

Comment: Plagiarism is passing off someone else's content as your own without giving them credit. While Wikipedia might be public domain, you still can't copy-paste from the site without directly stating that the info is not your own. As Unionhawk mentions, copyright infringement and plagiarism are not the same thing (though they are admittedly very similar).

Comment: @MageXy so wouldn't a very simple solution to just cite wikipedia in the tag? I still fail to see how it matters. I'm positive wikipedia does not care about your use of tags of all things.